# How can I parse a JSON file from Assets folder in UWP - Closed

Tags: c#, json, parsing, uwp, jsonparser

I am new developing windows UWP app and I am trying to parse a JSON file from my assets folder. I've seen many tutorials, but when I tried they don't work. Please, someone help me to parse it and if you can with an example.

I am using VS2017 and C#;

This is the library that I want to use:

```
using Windows.Data.Json;
```

My code is:

```
private Uri appUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/marker.json");
private string title;
private void ConverJSONtoObjects()
        {
            try
            {
                Uri appUri = new Uri(fileName);//File name should be prefixed with 'ms-appx:///Assets/* 
                StorageFile anjFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(appUri).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
                string jsonText = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(anjFile).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
                JsonArray obj = JsonValue.Parse(jsonText).GetArray();
                for (uint i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
                {
                    title = obj.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("name");
                }
                message("Place", title);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message("Error", ex.ToString());
            }
            
        }
```

I'm getting this error:
[error handled by Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im6PE.png)

My file is like this:

```
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"CabaÃ±as Nuevo Amanecer",
"lat":"18.402785",
"lng":"-70.094953",
"type":"Normal",
"phone":"No Disponible",
"price":"DOP 500",
"image":"http://i65.tinypic.com/10mif69.jpg"
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"CabaÃ±as Costa Azul",
"lat":"18.424746",
"lng":" -69.990333",
"type":"Lujosa",
"phone":"(809) 539-6969",
"price":"DOP 4453",
"image":"http://i64.tinypic.com/wcd5b8.png"
}
]
```

**Solution (updated 2021/11/7)**

Hi, for those how have the same problem, the issue was in the file properties: **The build action needs to be Content** for being able to call a file from the Assets folder in UWP

Comment: You should provide more details about what you don't understand because if you just want parsing, it's as simple as Windows.Data.Json.JArray.Parse(jsonString);

Comment: @CyprienAutexier Let's see if this helps you

Comment: And what's the problem with that code then? (Besides title is not declared and message is outside of the loop and will always display the last value)

Comment: I am getting this error: http://i68.tinypic.com/67o3zc.png

Comment: It has nothing to do with Json parsing :) It's not finding your file which means your Uri is invalid.Your file probably doesn't have the right Build Action or your Uri does not match it's location / name.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the file properties. The build action needs to be Content

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for one of the innumerable JSON libraries. You should start with [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which is the most popular choice. (You can have a look at alternatives such as [Service Stack Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), [FastJsonParser](https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser) or [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil)).

A simple way would be to declare a class matching your expected data schema:

```
public class PointOfInterest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And the use deserialization.:

```
var poiArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PointOfInterest[]>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
    });
```

Edit so with your updated requirement you would have to do things like this :

```
var array = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

foreach(JObject item in array){
   var poi = new PointOfInterest()
   poi.Id = (int)item.GetNamedNumber("id");
   //...
}
```

The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/94875e43-4e0c-499f-b409-317bcd306d3e) is pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks, the only problem is that I do not want to use external libraries to those of Windows unless it is my last option. I could make it work with an HTTPClient Request, but I want it works from my assets folder

Comment: @MisterJJ you can then use DataContractSerializer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx but: this is rubbish (very limited feature support and slow). For instance Miscrosoft AspNet Core team has opted for Json.Net to support Json.